# Use TextFSM to find allowed VLANs on trunk

Tags: python, regex, ansible, text-parsing, python-textfsm

I'm trying to set up a TextFSM template for NTC ansible which will only pull the Vlans allowed on the trunk from the output of a "show interface  trunk" command and can't seem to get what I want.  It is giving me all the lines instead of just the single line that I want.  The output of the command looks like this:

```
switch#sh int g9/17 trunk

Port                Mode         Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi9/17              on           802.1q         trunking      1

Port                Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi9/17              501,503,513,540,950-957

Port                Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi9/17              501,503,513,540,950-957

Port                Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi9/17              501,503,513,540,950-957
```

In this output, I only want to return the line below "Vlans allowed on trunk" and not the other repeat lines that have the same info.  My template looks like this:

```
Value PORT (\S+)
Value VLANS (.*)

Start
  ^Port.*Vlans allowed on trunk -> Begin

Begin
  ^(?=\s{0,9}${PORT})\s+${VLANS} -> Record
  ^Port.*Vlans allowed and active in management domain -> End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make regular expressions more specific and get the desired result (maybe :).

```
import io
import textfsm

template = io.StringIO("""\
Value Port (\S+(/\d+)?)
Value Vlans (\d+([-,]\d+)+)

Start
  ^Port\s+Vlans allowed on trunk$$ -> Begin

Begin
  ^${Port}\s+${Vlans}$$ -> Record
  ^Port\s+Vlans allowed and active in management domain$$ -> End
""")
fsm = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
result = fsm.ParseText("""\
switch#sh int g9/17 trunk

Port                Mode         Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi9/17              on           802.1q         trunking      1

Port                Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi9/17              501,503,513,540,950-957

Port                Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi9/17              501,503,513,540,950-957

Port                Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi9/17              501,503,513,540,950-957
""")
print(result)
```

```
[['Gi9/17', '501,503,513,540,950-957']]
```